# Meteor BlazeWhat is best practices? meteor .events vs jquery

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am pretty new to Meteor... What are the best practices for dealing with Events like drag and drop, click etc.

I understand there are two key ways:

1) in the Template..events where you use things like "click", "drop" etc

```
 Template.someTemplate.events({

    'click .some-button': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("clicked");
    },

});
```

2) in the Template..rendered where you just use $(some-selector).click(....  $(something).droppable etc etc

```
Template.resourcePage.rendered = function(){
    this.$('.some-button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("clicked");       

    });
 }
```

So to me this is the same thing, I think? This is just a simple example and the same things applies to other events like drop (in droppable()). 'drop' does not see to be on the formal list of supported Meteor events... so does this means I should use the #2 method.

What are the gotchas? Any work arounds?

cheers

Comment: you mean `Template.resourcePage.onRendered( function () {` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor currently supports the following events in its eventmaps: click, dblclick, focus, blur, change, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousedown, mouseup, keydown, keypress, keyup (your option 1)

Source: http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

If you want other events then the best place for them is indeed the rendered event(your option 2). Giving the button its own template greatly improves readability, testing and, possibly, performance.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of Meteor supports custom events (although it's not in the documentation). I am using it now and it works fine just like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'customEvent #button': function(event, template) {
    // can be called with $("#button").trigger( 'customEvent', {some_data: 'some data'} );
    // You can also access data, e.g. 'some data' is accessible at event.some_data
    console.log("clicked!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find some interesting info in [the Blaze wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) (scroll down to Events use jQuery). Other than that, events are defined in the .js file, not in the actual template (HTML file). Keep the jQuery out of the HTML files and try using template helpers, if you must.
Simply put, for a clicking event for an element #button in a template called myView this would be the code (best practice):

```
Template.myView.events = {
  'click #button' : function (event) {
    console.log("The button was clicked");
  }
}
```

That means you define which event happens within the Template.myView.events variable. There can be multiple events of course for the same template. You will find the event types to be used [in the Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events). You may use any jQuery code in your js file and the Template..events variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have been clearer with my question. I am not putting in jQuery in the HTML, all in the JS files. It seems like the two ways I have mentioned are similar but slightly different. Eg the :drop in the .events method seems to have (events) as Meteor parameter... where 'drop' inside a jQuery .droppable() statement has (event,ui) as params and you can do things like get the item them was dropped on the droppable (eg ui.draggable.clone) where I could not find this in the Meteor "event" param.